# Angular Material 2: Progress Bar animation choppy

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

I'm trying to build a page with Angular that has various progress bars that represent the progress made for an action that takes a set amount of time. What I'm trying to do is use the Angular Material progress bar to make a smooth animation from time 0 to the end time. My current solution is simply to update the percentage of the process every 50ms, and set the value of the progress bar to that value. I'm accomplishing this using the rxjs timer, as seen below:

```
const start = new Date().getTime();
const source = timer(0, 50);
const subscribe = source.subscribe(() => {
  const time = new Date().getTime();
  if (time - start > length) {
    subscribe.unsubscribe();
  }

  this.progressValue = 100 * (time - start) / length;
});
```

Here is the progress bar HTML itself:

```
 <mat-progress-bar mode="determinant" [value]="progressValue"></mat-progress-bar>
```

The result, however, is a very choppy progression of the progress bar. Is there a better way to do this? I know the length of the process every time, so I feel that a smooth transition for that amount of time should be relatively easy. Thanks!

Comment: Did you spell the `mode` property correctly? It should be `determinate` instead of `determinat`.

Comment: Whoops, looks like I did. However, mat-progress-bar defaults to determinate anyway, so unfortunately it didn't help to fix my problem.

Comment: If you dont mind, i am doing something similar what does the length stand for

Comment: If you want a smooth animation, you can only update the progress bar every 250ms, since the transition-duration of the .mat-progress-bar-fill is 250ms

Answer (score 1):

here is what I came up with:

html

```html
<mat-progress-bar color="accent" mode="determinate" [value]="uploadPercentage$ | async"></mat-progress-bar>
```

component:

```js
@ViewChild(MatProgressBar) progressBar: MatProgressBar;
uploadPercentage$: Observable<number>;
uploadProgress$: Subject<HttpProgressEvent> = new Subject<HttpProgressEvent>();

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // wait until animation ends and only then change value
    this.uploadPercentage$ = this.progressBar.animationEnd
      .pipe(
        startWith({
          value: 0
        }),
        switchMap((animationState: ProgressAnimationEnd) => this.uploadProgress$
          .pipe(
            map((progress: HttpProgressEvent): number => this.progressToPercents(progress)),
            distinctUntilChanged((val: number) => animationState.value !== val)
          )
        ),
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created my own progress bar with Angular Animations. This has a smooth transition and looks just like **mat-progress-bar**:

**1) add Animations to your component:**

```
  selector: 'app-loading',
  templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('loading', [
      state('start',
        style({
          width: '0%'
        })
      ),
      state('end',
        style({
          width: '100%'
        })),

      transition('start => end', [
        animate(2000)
      ]),
    ])
  ]
})
```

**2) set a trigger timer to start animation. I close the dialog after progress ends:**

```
duration: number = 2 * 100;
step = 100;
add_step = 10;
progress = 0;


ngOnInit() {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.progress < this.duration) {
        this.progress += this.add_step ;
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
    }, this.step);
  }
```

**3) use it in Html:**

```
<div style="background-color: #ff7a7a;height: 4px;width: 100%;">
        <div style="background-color: #760000;height: 4px;"
             [@loading]="progress === 0 ? 'start':'end'">
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Nodarii answer but simpler :

HTML:

```
<mat-progress-bar color="accent" mode="determinate" [value]="uploadPercentage$ | async"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild(MatProgressBar) progressBar: MatProgressBar;
uploadPercentage$: Observable<number>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.uploadPercentage$ = this.progressBar.animationEnd.pipe(
      startWith(0),
      delay(0),
      map(() => this.yourPercentage)
    );
  }
```

Angular Material do the animation ;)